# Why am I getting different results with my code?

Tags: r

I want to figure out how many cards in the deck are either of the suit spades OR have an even value but I can't understand out why I get different answers depending on how I write the last sections of code. The answer I'm looking to get is 31.

```
Suits <- c("Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades") 
Value <- 1:13

Deck <- expand.grid(Value = Value, Suits = Suits) 
Deck$Cards <- paste(Deck$Suits, Deck$Value)

Hearts <- subset(Deck, Suits == "Hearts", "Cards")
Nines <- subset(Deck, Value == 9, "Cards")


Spades <- subset(Deck, Suits == "Spades", "Cards")
Even_Value <- subset(Deck, Value %% 2 == 0, "Cards") 
length(union(Spades, Even_Value))

Spades <- Deck[Deck$Suits == "Spades", "Cards"]
Even_Value <- Deck[Deck$Value %% 2 == 0, "Cards"]
length(union(Spades, Even_Value))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subset` function returns a data frame with a single column, whereas the expression `Deck[Deck$Suits == "Spades", "Cards"]` returns a vector. These are not the same thing. In particular, when you try to do a `union` of two data frames, you will not get a single vector, but a list with one entry for each column in each data frame.

```r
Spades <- subset(Deck, Suits == "Spades", "Cards")
Even_Value <- subset(Deck, Value %% 2 == 0, "Cards") 
union(Spades, Even_Value)
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] "Spades 1"  "Spades 2"  "Spades 3"  "Spades 4"  "Spades 5"  "Spades 6"  "Spades 7" 
#>  [8] "Spades 8"  "Spades 9"  "Spades 10" "Spades 11" "Spades 12" "Spades 13"
#>
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] "Diamonds 2"  "Diamonds 4"  "Diamonds 6"  "Diamonds 8"  "Diamonds 10" "Diamonds 12"
#>  [7] "Clubs 2"     "Clubs 4"     "Clubs 6"     "Clubs 8"     "Clubs 10"    "Clubs 12"   
#> [13] "Hearts 2"    "Hearts 4"    "Hearts 6"    "Hearts 8"    "Hearts 10"   "Hearts 12"  
#> [19] "Spades 2"    "Spades 4"    "Spades 6"    "Spades 8"    "Spades 10"   "Spades 12"
```

Since you passed two data frames each with one column, there are 2 * 1 = 2 vectors in the resulting list, so it is a list of length 2.

Similarly if you did a `union` of the built-in data sets `iris` and `mtcars`, you would get a list of 16 vectors (all 5 columns from `iris` and all 11 columns from `mtcars`):

```r
ncol(mtcars)
#> [1] 11
ncol(iris)
#> [1] 5
length(union(mtcars, iris))
#> [1] 16
```

However, the second version performs the union of two *vectors* rather than two *dataframes*, and the `union` of these two vectors will be correct:

```
Spades <- Deck[Deck$Suits == "Spades", "Cards"]
Even_Value <- Deck[Deck$Value %% 2 == 0, "Cards"]
union(Spades, Even_Value)
#>  [1] "Spades 1"    "Spades 2"    "Spades 3"    "Spades 4"    "Spades 5"    "Spades 6"   
#>  [7] "Spades 7"    "Spades 8"    "Spades 9"    "Spades 10"   "Spades 11"   "Spades 12"  
#> [13] "Spades 13"   "Diamonds 2"  "Diamonds 4"  "Diamonds 6"  "Diamonds 8"  "Diamonds 10"
#> [19] "Diamonds 12" "Clubs 2"     "Clubs 4"     "Clubs 6"     "Clubs 8"     "Clubs 10"   
#> [25] "Clubs 12"    "Hearts 2"    "Hearts 4"    "Hearts 6"    "Hearts 8"    "Hearts 10"  
#> [31] "Hearts 12"
```

To make the first version work, you must select the column of the data frame from which you wish to make the union (in each case, it is the only column - `Cards`, but this still needs to be selected to obtain the vector *in* the data frame rather than the data frame itself)

```
Spades <- subset(Deck, Suits == "Spades", "Cards")
Even_Value <- subset(Deck, Value %% 2 == 0, "Cards") 
length(union(Spades$Cards, Even_Value$Cards))
#> [1] 31
```

Comment: to get the same result you can add `drop = TRUE` to subset. Another way is to use `nrow` instead of `length` in both statements and set `drop = FALSE` in the second one (`Deck[.., drop = FALSE]`). The default value of `drop` is one of the differences between `subset` and `[`.

Comment: @Edo yes, the `subset.data.frame` method actually uses the `[` operator in its final line. My understanding is that the main benefit of using `subset` is to allow non-standard evaluation (not unlike `dplyr::filter`), which the `[` operator doesn't do - but the default `drop = FALSE` is indeed an important difference.